# Futures Holiday Schedule

Tags: trading, futures

I am trying to find a place where I can get S&P Emini contract trading days. I would like to get the contract first appearance (September 9th 1997) until today.

I can get  [Holidays](http://www.cmegroup.com/tools-information/holiday-calendar/) but nothing for 1997. Is there a place where I can find this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use a specific holiday code while downloading the schedule from Bloomberg ("cdr = CE", in the API formula). if not, you might have to rely on wikipedia or other public source, and just remove the holidays from a more complete list. While the date changes every year, the HOLIDAYS doesn't.